# How to allocate, initialize, and reallocate an array of pointers to char?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I've been trying to make a search result list, and if it needs mores space, realloc it. 
I had an implementation almost working but I couldn't figure out how to resize an array to hold more strings.

The original:
    char  *searchResults[maxResults];

Another function would malloc each searchResults[i] to the proper size when a hit was found.  This is how it would look with a couple search results:

```
searchResults[0] = "Result"
searchResults[1] = "AnotherResult"
searchResults[2] = "Someresulthere"
searchResults[3] = "TheFourthresult"
searchResults[4] = "YetAnotherOne"
```

After trying to reallocate it when it ran out of space, and failing, I turned to the internet and apparently you can't resize arrays. Fortunately, or so I thought I the time, a couple sites said to do:

```
char **searchResults;

//initialize result list
searchResults = (char **) malloc( maxResults * sizeof(char *) ) ;
for (i = 0; i < maxResults; i++) {
searchResults[i] = NULL ;
```

Well, that doesn't seem to work at all. I've spent a few hours trying to figure this out and now I'm just plain stymied. It will allocate 400 bytes for searchResults(maxResults is 100), and the address for searchResults[i] changes by 4 bytes, but nothing happens. If I malloc(100) to searchResults[i], it seems to to allocate the space but I still don't seem to be able to store anything except for one result at searchresult[0].

When viewing searchResults it always looks like:

```
searchResults[0] = "someResult"
```

Whereas the first example is how it should look.  I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what.

Thanks

EDIT:  If you downvote, you could at least have the common courtesy to say why so I can provide clarification on whatever your point of discord is.

Anyways, here's an image showing the problem. I can't seem to assign any results except to the the first element and I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: Your `malloc` code is fine (apart from the needless cast and the lack of error checking). Clearly you have a problem. An SSCCE would allow us to find the problem. It's never any good saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: `searchResults[i] = (char*)malloc(100)` so ,`strcpy(searchResults[0], "DDDDDDDDDD");` (or use strncpy) instead of `searchResults[0] = "DDDDDDDDDD"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I deleted the project, remade it, commented out that assigning values to each pointer, and it works exactly as it should now. What was the issue? No idea, corrupt project I guess.

On a side note, Visual Studio doesn't show in the debugger the values of the various pointers stored using char **searchResults method.

Answer (score -1):

To find out how to increase the size of the array once it is full Please read the working of `realloc` function properly.
I think using `realloc` properly should solve your problem.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char *str;

   /* Initial memory allocation */
   str = (char *) malloc(15);
   strcpy(str, "tutorialspoint");
   printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);

   /* Reallocating memory */
   str = (char *) realloc(str, 25);
   strcat(str, ".com");
   printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);

   free(str);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: I guess you could elaborate more.

Comment: example added in answer